# Why wrong @MapperScan can run ok

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I create a simple spring boot project, with mybatis plus, and I can run it well with `@MapperScan("xxx.xxx.xxx.Mapper")`. However, my mapper files are in folder `xxx/xxx/xxx/mapper`, so it is weird. With `@MapperScan("xxx.xxx.xxx.Mapper")`, I can run project right, but after package it as jar, run jar file will get error that bean factory can't find mapper bean. After correct it, `@MapperScan("xxx.xxx.xxx.mapper")`, and package the project, the error disappears.
I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Are you asking why Java is case-sensitive?

Comment: Emm, Java is case-sensitive, but why this wrong annotation can go well in spring boot?

Comment: What do you mean by "go well"?

Comment: This spring boot project can run well, and each controller  works as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case-sensitive, including package names. You are running on Windows, and in general the NTFS filesystem is not case-sensitive. Most likely, when Boot is performing its scan, the incorrect `Mapper` happens to match the actual directory name `mapper` in NTFS, and it finds your bean, but when it packages up the jar, it uses the real package name inside and doesn't match.

Comment: Well, I got it. It  is related to file system. Thanks very much.